# exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH although it does exist?

Tags: docker, cmd

I have been struggling with the issue of "docker" command not being recognized in Windows cmd. I have docker installed on Windows Pro, and it is running ok, but the "docker" command is not recognized though the PATH variable contain the location of the docker binaries.

Any ideas on this, please? I have been looking everywhere, but could not find a solution!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I encontered the same problem. In my case (*linux*) **it was because of broken installations**. I've ran `sudo apt --fix-broken install && sudo apt install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

Answer (score 0):

(Windows): I did not use my PC for a year, and got the same error after running `docker --version`. I just upgraded to the latest docker version, and issue resolved.